# Creating UserControl Via Webpart. i need css file import but how?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

Everything is ok. i van  see StyleSheet.css in page source.But css effect can not run my gridview. How can i do that

```
 public class MyGridView : WebPart
    {
        GridView gvCustomers;

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            gvCustomers = new GridView();
            HtmlHead head = (HtmlHead)Page.Header;
            HtmlLink link = new HtmlLink();
            link.Attributes.Add("href", Page.ResolveClientUrl("StyleSheet.css"));
            link.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
            link.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
            head.Controls.Add(link);

            gvCustomers.CssClass = "tablestyle";
            gvCustomers.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "headerstyle";
            gvCustomers.AlternatingRowStyle.CssClass = "altrowstyle";
            gvCustomers.RowStyle.CssClass = "rowstyle";
            this.Controls.Add(gvCustomers);
        }

        public object DataSource
        {
            get {
                this.EnsureChildControls();
                return gvCustomers.DataSource; }
            set {
                this.EnsureChildControls();

                gvCustomers.DataSource = value; }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried a ScriptManagerProxy control? using this control within your user control can determine if the CSS has already been added to your page, and only add one reference to your css file
(I would post this an an answer, but darn 3 minute answer rule sucks!)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a ScriptManagerProxy control? using this control within your user control can determine if the CSS has already been added to your page, and only add one reference to your css file

Comment: sorry for the late response:

    <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="smpScriptAdder" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Javascript/MyResource.css" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManagerProxy>